# Problems with ee$List$repeat

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I am trying to get the following code to work in Google Earth Engine using the `rgee` package:

```
# Load rgee
library(rgee)

# Initialise
ee_users()
ee_Initialize()

# The incorrect use of repeat within an rgee context
ee$List$repeat(1,3)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: unexpected 'repeat' in "ee$List$repeat"
```

Is it because there is some confusion with `repeat` in base r?

Comment: Have you tried putting `repeat` in backticks, "`"?  It's a reserved word in R.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise you could do that...

Comment: @user2554330 It might be worth posting that as an answer. I'd upvote it. There is some chance someone could search for the same thing.

Comment: @IanCampbell:  I'm not going to put it in an answer, but feel free to go ahead.  The question doesn't include a reproducible example, so it should be closed.

Comment: I added some further code to hopefully make this reproduceable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For R reserved words use backticks/quotation marks:

```r
    # Load rgee
    library(rgee)
    
    # Initialise
    ee_users()
    ee_Initialize()
    
    # The incorrect use of repeat within an rgee context
    ee$List$'repeat'(1,3)$map( 
        ee_utils_pyfunc( #ee_utils_pyfunc is necessary to apply a map function to an ee$List
          function(x) {
            ee$Number(x)$add(1)
          }
        )    
    )
```